# spring-security-taglib maven dependency ignored

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring STS and have a spring mvc web application and have changed my pom.xml to include the following dependency...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

For some reason Maven does not like this and although spring-security-taglibs-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar is being downloaded into my maven repositories the jar is not being included on the project path.

Hence I get an error when I try and do this.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

I'm thinking this could be some kind of dependency conflict or something. Does anyone have any ideas? Here is the rest of my pom.

```
<dependencies>      
    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a maven issue, check if the jar is being shown in the dependencies. If yes try adding it to build path.

Answer (score 1):

This jar do you put inside of your war ?
I faced this problem and it was solved get off of the server folder and put in war.

Comment: So do you mean that you had to manually add this jar as an in project repository? I still have the problem.

Comment: @Richie in my case I was putting the dependencies on the server, then I faced this problem, to not face again I put **spring-security-taglibs** inside my war. But probably you trying run your app through an IDE. I suggest you to use the maven to package your app and run it.